# Knex stop listening on events

Tags: events, knex.js

I create a listening for knex like this:

```
knex.on('query', (query) => {
    console.log(`Executed a query: ${query.__knexQueryUid}`);
  }) 
  .on('query-response', (response, query) => {
    console.log(`Received a response from: ${query.__knexQueryUid}`);

    // Here I will log query, response, req.url, req.method, and other req parameters.

  })
```

(Reference: [Timing Your Queries in Knex.js for Node.js](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/03/27/timing-queries-knexjs-nodejs/))

**How can I stop this listening on the events?**

My purpose is to log the URL of the API (as well as the query and response in the call back function above), so what I need is a separate listening for each API call to the server (My server allows to connect to different databases also).